# Can I use @import to import Kod's default style sheet into my own?

Tags: macos, text-editors, css

I understand that [Kod](http://kodapp.com/) is being actively developed and is prone to drastic changes in any area. I would like to modify some small things (like font face and size or certain colors) while still being able to benefit from any changes or updates to the default Kod stylesheet.

I thought that I would be able to `@import` the default stylesheet into my own to achieve this. This is what `~/.kod/custom.css` would look like,

```
@import url("file:///Applications/Kod.app/Contents/Resources/style/default.css");

/* Change the default font face and color. */
body {
    font-family: Menlo, monospace;
    color: #efefef;
}
```

This stylesheet was set with the following `defaults` command, per the comments at the top of Kod's default CSS file:

```
defaults write se.hunch.kod style/url ~/.kod/custom.css
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work. When I first tried to reload the style, Kod crashed. It opened fine again, but

- the `@import` statement wasn't working, and
- Kod crashed every time I saved the `custom.css` file.

Am I doing something wrong? Did I write my `@import` statement wrong? Is that not how `@import` is supposed to work? Did I miss some sort of documentation or Kod Google Groups post that mentions that Kod explicitly disallows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Kod does not support `@import` statements in the CSS.

As a workaround, you can use version control software. I have no experience with `git`, which this Kod folks use, but you can probably set up a local copy of `https://github.com/rsms/kod/tree/master/resources/style` somewhere, and keep this updated whenever you update Kod itself. Keep your own changes, and they'll be merged with any updates to these files.

Comment: Do you have a reference or link to some source that definitively says that Kod doesn't support `@import` statements?

Comment: @Thomas Besides it also not working for me, no.

Comment: For some reason, it's now crashing all the time, so I cannot continue to investigate. Sorry.